# R 'memisc' package: why has "as.data.frame()" changed 0/1 values of data.set to 1/2 in data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, spss

I'm trying to prepare an SPSS .sav data file with survey data for performing analyses in R.
Now I have an issue that some variables with binary values 0/1 (signifying no/yes) have been transformed unexpectedly.

I have used the `memisc` package to import the data as a **data.set** object.

```
Dset.core <- spss.system.file(file="C://..../data_coded.sav",
                            varlab.file=NULL,
                            codes.file=NULL,
                            missval.file=NULL,
                            count.cases=TRUE,
                            to.lower=FALSE      
)
```

This worked all fine, from what I saw from `str()` and `codebook()` outputs. One example of a 0/1 variable **$AMEVYES** (labels are 0=no, 1=yes) is shown here:

```
str(Dset.core)
```

> Data set with 1999 obs. of 106 variables:
>
> > (...)
> >     $ AMEVYES : Nmnl. item w/ 2 labels for 0,1 num 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...

I now want to convert the special data.set object created by `memisc` into a data frame with:

```
Dset2Df.core <- as.data.frame(Dset.core)
```

As intended, the nominal 0/1 variable was changed into a factor  variable with corresponding levels. But for some strange reason, this procedure also changed the **values** of the variables, **from 0/1 to 1/2**, like in this example output:

```
str(Dset2Df.core)
```

> 'data.frame': 1999 obs. of 106 variables:
>
> > (...)
> >     $ AMEVYES : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...

Why did this happen, and most importantly, **how can I stop this from happening**?
Many thanks for a hint!

PS: I'm rather new to R and new to this forum, so please excuse if I missed any best practices when formulating my question.

Comment: Stumbled upon this question when I was looking for something else. Regarding your question; we are missing a [practical reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Instead of all 1999 rows of 106 variables, why not show 5 rows? `head(Dset2Df.core$AMEVYES, 5)`. Also, the desired output is unclear, do you want keep `"Yes", "No"` AND `0,1`?

Answer (score 1):

As [The Carpentries](https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/12-supp-factors/index.html) states:

> **Factors are stored as integers, and have labels associated with these
>   unique integers**. While factors look (and often behave) like character
>   vectors, they are actually integers under the hood, and you need to be
>   careful when treating them like strings.

Factors are internally stored as integers starting from 1. **You cannot change** these internally stored values. You can, however, change their labels `("Yes", "No")` or `(0, 1)`.